# Login RedirectUrl with AngularJS & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-identity

I have an angular website that is served using MVC pages with ASP.NET Identity cookies. There is an MVC page for the login, and then an MVC page for the index.html which has the `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller.

It works fine, except for one thing: When I am not logged in, and I go to `www.site.com/restricterurl`, I would like to have the page redirect me to `www.site.com/login?ReturnUrl=%2Frestrictedurl`. Then on logging in, I can redirect to the originally requested url. This is a typical login requirement.

However, no matter what URL I try access when logged out, I always get sent to `/login?ReturnUrl=%2F`, i.e. a ReturnUrl that will redirect to the home (index) page. I suspect this is because I have a UrlRewrite in web.config that rewrites `/restrictedurl` to `/` so that (if you're already logged in and access that url) the index page would be served and angular would initialize to the correct `restrictedurl` route/url. I.e. that UrlRewrite handles the case where you get logged in with the cookie, and the original Url takes you to the route / page where you wanted to be.

So how do I get the authentication, angular, the url rewrite and MVC to play nicely for **both** these cases:

1. when logged in and starting at a url, to serve index.html and let angular set the correct route.
2. when **not** logged in and starting at a url, to redirect to the login url with the requested url as a querystring parameter.

Some code:

In my startup I have:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
    //....
```

My web.config has:

```
<rule name="Index" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/login" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/logout" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```